# How to remove partpage numbering from part pages in beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering

I am using he following code to generate a part-page in beamer:

```
{{{
\part{title of part}
\frame{\partpage}
}}}
```

In addition to drawing a nice box with the title it writes "Part I" above this box. Is there a way to remove this part numbering and leave only the box with the specified title within `\part{}`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Answer (score 5):

With the usage of `\setbeamertemplate{part page}{...}` you can simply define your own part page.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}{
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,wd=\textwidth]{part title}
            \usebeamerfont{part title}\insertpart\par
        \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

    \part{eqrfv}

    \begin{frame}
        \partpage
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]